# Bar chart with 4 datasets, need 2 datasets stacked per scale

Tags: chart.js

I need the following chart to stack the orange and green items on top of each other. For some reason, they do not stack up.

[image]

Options are configured like this:

```json
{
  responsive: true,
  legend: {
    display: true,
    position: 'top',
  },
  scales: {
    requests: {
      display: true,
      position: 'left',
      type: 'linear',
      stacked: true,
    },
    CEV: {
      display: true,
      position: 'right',
      type: 'linear',
      stacked: true,
    }
  },
}
```

data is as follows:

```json
{
  "labels": [
      "Jun 23"
  ],
  "datasets": [
      {
          "label": "Other",
          "id": "Other",
          "yAxisID": "requests",
          "data": [
              10
          ],
          "backgroundColor": [
              "rgba(255, 139, 32, 0.2)"
          ],
          "borderColor": [
              "rgba(255, 139, 32, 1)"
          ],
          "borderWidth": 1
      },
      {
          "label": "Won",
          "id": "Won",
          "yAxisID": "requests",
          "data": [
              1
          ],
          "backgroundColor": [
              "rgba(120, 255, 132, 0.2)"
          ],
          "borderColor": [
              "rgba(120, 255, 132, 1)"
          ],
          "borderWidth": 1
      },
      {
          "label": "Other (CEV)",
          "id": "OtherCEV",
          "yAxisID": "CEV",
          "data": [
              6298315.57
          ],
          "backgroundColor": [
              "rgba(255, 139, 32, 0.2)"
          ],
          "borderColor": [
              "rgba(255, 139, 32, 1)"
          ],
          "borderWidth": 1
      },
      {
          "label": "Won (CEV)",
          "id": "WonCEV",
          "yAxisID": "CEV",
          "data": [
              114351.12
          ],
          "backgroundColor": [
              "rgba(120, 255, 132, 0.2)"
          ],
          "borderColor": [
              "rgba(120, 255, 132, 1)"
          ],
          "borderWidth": 1
      }
  ]
}
```

The scales work properly but how do I stack the `Won` and `Won (CEV)` items on top of the corresponding `Other` items?

I have tried multiple settings, including setting `x` as stacked but it stacks all 4 datasets together.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have to set the [`stack`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#general) property for each dataset object. Each pair of bars that you want one over the other should have the same value of this `stack` parameter, that can be an arbitrary string that identifies that stack (e.g., `stack: "stackYellow"` and `stack: "stackGreen"`). See [this example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/stacked-groups.html) that uses `stack: "Stack 0"` and `stack: "Stack 1"`

Comment: This worked. Thanks! If you would like me to set this as the answer, please post the the same as the answer and not as a comment